# Can I use Gmail's Canned Response to forward to a different address?

Tags: gmail, gmail-canned-response

Is there a way to use Canned Response to automatically forward, rather than reply?

**Context**

I regularly receive system generated emails, which I need to forward to another human to request their action. I'd like to automate this step, however Canned Responses seems to insist that my reply goes to the original sender.

I've tried configuring this by trial and error, but the closest I've got is where CR replies to the original sender, *and* forwards to the new address.

Note that I can't have the emails sent directly to that other human, nor can I use Google Apps Scripts, due to business rules.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the **Forwarding** feature of Gmail to set up filters and have them auto-forward.

1. Login to http://gmail.com/.
2. Click the **cog** icon and select **Settings**.
3. Open the **Forwarding and POP/IMAP** tab and locate the **Forwarding** section.
4. Click **Add a forwarding address** and enter the email address of one of the human users that the emails will be automatically forwarded to.

   - NOTE: They will receive a confirmation email that contains a confirmation code. They must confirm this action or give you the confirmation code to enter before you can continue with the steps.
5. Once the email address/es have been confirmed, repeat steps 1-3.
6. Click the link **creating a filter!**
7. From the field that appears, enter the corresponding details. For example:

   - **From**: The address that the automated emails come from.
   - **To**: The human user who will be handling this specific job.
   - **Subject**: If the automated email for this job has the same subject each time, enter it here.
   - **Has the words**: If there is anything unique about the automated email, enter it here.
8. Click the **Test Search** button to confirm that the correct emails are being detected.
9. When happy with the filter, click **Create filter with this search**
10. The results will now show up in the inbox. Select the **Forward it to** check box and select the corresponding email address.
11. If you want the email removed from *your* inbox automatically after it has been forwarded, select **Skip the Inbox** or **Delete it**.
12. Click **Create filter**.

**NOTE**: This method is dependent on the emails being sent to *your* email address. If someone else takes over your role, this same procedure will need to be done for emails sent to their account.

Filters can be exported, imported, and deleted from the **Filters and Blocked Addresses** tab of Gmail settings.